# How to follow an xpath without a hierarchy?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am going through some "badly" designed pages that have a hierarchy that looks something like this...

```
<h1>
    <span id=English>English</span>
</h1>
<div>go</div>
<p>verb - to move from one place to another</p>
<h1 id=Spanish>Spanish</h1>
<div>va</div>
<p>verb - to move from one place to another</p>
```

The point here is that things are not hierarchical and I need a way to get the p (or whatever else) that comes after a certain id without going down in the hierarchy.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `following-sibling::p` and limit the result to `1`. For example, the following XPath should return `<p>verb - to move from one place to another</p>` :

```
//h1[@id='Spanish']/following-sibling::p[1]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works well but while taking another look at the path, it is a bit more compliacated. I need to take a step into the heirarchy, get by id and then step back out to get the siblings, I have updated my answer, I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @deltaskelta `//h1[span/@id='English']/following-sibling::p[1]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try by using [preceding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding) axes as below :-

```
//p[preceding::h1[@id='Spanish']]
```

Hope it helps...:)